# c# I want to make code that requires admin from a button, and do not open the app with permission, how do i make this?

Tags: c#, windows, privileges

I have a project, but I don't want to have to open it with admin permission, but a button that requires that admin. is there any code to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please be careful when selecting tags, so you don't select the C language tag instead of C#. Please [edit] your question to fix that mistake.

Comment: You make this by writing code, if you have code you attempted and put that in your question and why/what challenges you had making it work we might be able to better assist you here.

Answer (score -1):

You mean something like this?

```
using System.Security.Principal;

private static bool AdminRightsCheck()
{
    using (WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
    {
        WindowsPrincipal p = new WindowsPrincipal(user);
        return p.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
}
```